# Wii Guitar Hero World Tour microphone

Tags: nintendo-wii, audio-hardware, guitar-hero, guitar-hero-world-tour

What kind of microphones are supported by Wii Guitar Hero World Tour? I bought a box which contained one guitar only and would like to get a complete kit; two guitars, drums and microphone.

Can I use a PS2 Sing Star microphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, there is no definitive answer for the general case of USB mics.

[Here an echantillon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6532/wii-guitar-hero-world-tour-microphone) of my search:

> Since you're on Wii, not too many mics
>   have been made for it (at least here
>   in the u.s.) **MOST usb mics will work.**
>   I own a GH and a RB mic along with a
>   Disney Logitech mic and they all work
>   with RB and GH.

So it's a case of Trial and error...

For the particular case of the **PS2 Sing Star microphone**, I would said [I'm not certain, but likely not.](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1120191)

> I actually bought the wired Singstar mic yesterday and tried on GH5 on Wii and it doesn't work. :(